# c++ Segmentation fault occurs when executing simple opengl tutorial

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to use opengl to render objects. Although the simple tutorial example http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/get_opengl_setup_linux/text.phpcompiles without error when I attempt to execute the program it crashes i.e. the dreaded segmentation fault.

System

Suse Linux 11.2 64 bit

g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839]
Eclipse IDE Build id: 20100218-1602

according to yast 64bit freeglut and freeglut-devel are installed:

090301-3.1
libglut.so.3()(64bit)
mesaglut
freeglut = 090301-3.1
freeglut(x86-64) = 090301-3.1

Is this a 64 bit vs 32 bit issue? I have had the same example program working under suse 11.1 32bit.

Any help would be appreciated

---

Okay .Car has been pushed back up the hill and loose nut tightened.

Below is output from gdb:

```
~/workspaceNew/cubetest/Default> gdb 
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (6.8.91.20090930-2.4)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...

(gdb) run ./cubetest
Starting program: /home/mark/workspaceNew/cubetest/Default/cubetest ./cubetest

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=591af1afa33f255704fb6a60859b93d00e205302"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=768ca903dcb7f43b3a9f4cdc368d9469e44c14f7"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=a76155345771ffa204fc8a1cf63b3eca7ce1ae86"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=62220ad5c8941afb5d332c0c47d32f8beec8ac50"

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libm.so.6

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=57fc1891d8d9f419fb8c7fc06a8285563b53a47e"

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=0206e11fa8ca0db0633073adcbf1349a7871e1dc"

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libc.so.6

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=b5ded0f18b9b11c5cd6b26387426ead562c332f8"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=cb5a2f35ed226cb1c92f063d03b204ec24b100a6"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=5fa84adc30db95abcbaea20ed7ec1c8dd94dfff2"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=4ffef26febce96a31b2d5df10538bb6dba112e3b"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=79d5f89d13f43ff26518ec8dd46fecfad911f968"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=650d88fdf900daadd8ba1c9134c21b4e68b560bc"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=6495446f04c2f9a4fa3021f7322d6f12c4017305"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=dc7d692fb4a36fa25fc513b2e36a614f5e4efc48"

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libpthread.so.0

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=7bcbabc9da24424f1f5ef7be77b575fd3d796288"

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libdl.so.2

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=44e66ebae672563bd496f290e08d316bc3bf0ac7"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=54a77c10d44b40080d6d8e65d277ccb7ab2a5b4a"

Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/librt.so.1

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=c663e79551b37d4c0c9bc93b252b917bfdedb150"

Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libXau.so.
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=72341bb9d8a1ad2ca2bbced007f3a785121aac28"

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bbeaf7 in fgOpenWindow () from /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3
```

> ```
> (gdb) bt
>
>
> #0  0x00007ffff7bbeaf7 in fgOpenWindow () from /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3
> #1  0x00007ffff7bbd0fc in fgCreateWindow () from /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3
> #2  0x00007ffff7bbe3d2 in glutCreateWindow () from /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3
> #3  0x0000000000402c45 in main (argc=2, argv=<value optimized out>) at ../cube/main.cpp:191
> ```

Comment: Where does it crash? Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger? Do you know where it crashes?

Comment: "Today my car stalled.  What is wrong?"

Comment: @John Dibling: What is the make and model of your car. Did you push it back to the top of the hill and try again ;-)

Comment: You've got a loose nut behind the keyboard.  Tighten that thing and everything should work itself out.

Comment: Does glxgears work on this system?

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I can say is that the example compiles and runs on Ubuntu 10.04 x64. I did have to add `-lGLU` to `LIBS` in the makefile, but since it already compiles for you, I guess that's not very helpful.

Your debug info does not provide a lot of insight; try installing -dbg packages for the relevant libraries.